# ASP.net Not able to display error using label control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error while trying to display an error message using `Label control` on asp.net form

**what I am trying to do:**

I want to show an error message using a Label control, if a user click on `Submit button` without selecting an option given in `dropdown control` and `textbox control`.

**What I have done:**

I have put code on .aspx is `lblControl.Visible="true"` and code on aspx.cs is inside Page_load- `if(!isPostBack){ lblControl.Visible="false";`

Then where I have handled the click->

```
if((txtbox.Text == "") & (ddlbox.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")) 
        {
            string Message = "Please select a value in drop down list, other than 'Select' and fill some value in text box.";
            lblControl.Visible = true;
            lblControl.Text = Message;          
        /* I have tried this one code also 
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "errMsg", script, true); //doesn't help */ 
        }
else{
save(); //another method to perform insert operation.
}
```

What is happening now: (As per my debug observation)
Whenever I am trying to display error message in the form of Label(control). The flow of program goes to Master page rather than display of Error message.

```
At the master we have placed various links related to show `logo image, ` logout link`  etc `inside <%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Modules.aspx")%>`
```

From there, `debugging` has halted & page has rendered without the message of `lblContorl`.

**Confusion-cum-question:** I am unable to understand this code-switch (flow of code getting child pages to Master pages)

many thanks for all types of suggestion!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: As a side-note *"Ensure drop down list is not equal to 'Select' and text box is not left blank."* is **not** a user-friendly error message.

Comment: Use if((String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text)) && ddlbox.SelectedIndex==-1)

Comment: @BugFinder page got halted without any message (output)

Comment: "if((if((txtbox.Text == "") & (ddlbox.SelectedItem.Text == "Select")) " doesnt read like valid code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Change your code to:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text) || ddlbox.SelectedItem.Text == "Select") 
{
    string message = "Your Error Message";

    lblControl.Text = message;  
    lblControl.Visible = true;     

    return; // optional   
}
else
{
    save(); //another method to perform insert operation.
}
```

What this does is if one or both statements are true, this code will be executed. In case you do not want any other code to run after this, add 'return;' after the last line of code in your if-statement.

Another way of showing errors in ASP.Net would be to use a **ValidationSummary**.

With this, you do not have to worry about making controls visible or not. 
Just add a ValidationSummary on your page where your Label is now - like this:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="myValidationSummary" CssClass="my-error-class" />
```

and change your code to:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox.Text) || ddlbox.SelectedItem.Text == "Select") 
{
    string message = "Your Error Message";

    ModelState.AddModelError("", message);     

    return;   
}
else
{
    save(); //another method to perform insert operation.
}
```

This way, there is no need to handle visibility and you can use this for DataBound Controls as well, so it might be worth looking into it.

EDIT: To use ModelState, you need to import ModelBinding. Just add:

```
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
```

to your Page. You can even use this in UserControls by simply calling

```
Page.ModelState.AddModelError("","Your Error Message");
```

You should be able to use this in ASP.NET without any problems.

> I am unable to understand this code-switch (flow of code getting child
>   pages to Master pages)

See [this Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to read about the ASP Page Lifecycle.

Comment: thanks for this clean solution with easy to understand solution. But, I have one question about `ModelState.AddModelError();` line of code - that, it is not available in `ASP.net` rather it is available in `ASP.net MVC framework` I have found some link https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/  explaining this. Thanks!